# How to make aria2c effectively handle "not at once" pipeline as job list file?

Tags: download, aria2

I would like to send jobs (files to download) to aria2c via stdin pipeline.
`aria2c -i -`

`aria2c` has failed to start downloads "at once" when new job had beed fed every few seconds. For 10+ short jobs it started download after input pipe has been closed.  Can it be fixed via command line options?

---

Sample shell script for tests [real script downloads over 50 URLs]:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
while read URL OUT; do
  echo $URL
  [ "$OUT" != "" ] && echo "  out=$OUT"
  sleep 1
done <<END | aria2c --deferred-input true -i -
http://example.com/
http://example.net/
http://example.org/
END
```

[`-i -` and "not all at once" pipe - Issue #1161](https://github.com/aria2/aria2/issues/1161)

P.S.
What I really like is "download server" without access for other hosts or other local users.  Something like "RPC via unix sockets" (access control via file permissions) would be acceptable.